# Factoring differential equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I was doing some reading on basic differential equations and the following equation came up:
$$
\left(\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x} + A(x)\right)\left(\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x} + B(x)\right) = \frac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d}x^2} + A(x)\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x} + A(x)B(x) + B'(x) + B(x)\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}
$$
what I'm confused about is that somehow, $\text{d}/\text{d}x$ both multiplied $B$ and differentiated $B$ (which is why both $B(x)\text{d}/\text{d}x$ and $B'(x)$ appeared on the RHS).

I've never seen this before, and I've never seen a justification for it. Why is this so?

Comment: Can you add some more context for where this appeared?  If you consider that as an equation of operators (i.e. understood with a $C^2$ function multiplied on the right of both sides), that looks like the product rule to me.

Comment: @JasonKnapp Here's a video demonstrating it (it's not the original text that I got the equation from, but I think it's similar in context). https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tV-xIhP7VU8& Specifically, the professor writes it on the board at around the 17th minute.

Comment: I see several equations that are similar, but not the same.  At any rate, yes, in that demonstration he is applying those objects to a function $y(x)$.  If you do these same in your equality, you will see that the term in the expansion $\frac{d}{dx} B(x) y(x)$ is just computed with the product rule, and yields the two terms you ask for on the right.

Comment: @JasonKnapp I'm not seeing it. Do you think you could post an answer to clarify?

Comment: Ok, done.  Hope I am understanding your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the left hand side to a function $y(x)$.
$$\left(\frac{d}{dx} + A(x)\right)\left(\frac{d}{dx} + B(x)\right)y(x)$$
Expand this expression.  The term you are interested in is $\frac{d}{dx}B(x)y(x)$.  Apply the product rule to obtain $B'(x) y(x) + B(x) y'(x)$.  Factor out $y$ to get $\left(B'(x) + B(x) \frac{d}{dx}\right)y(x)$.  This is just the term you were curious about, I believe.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks!